# Sum of column from subquery yields weird outcome

Tags: postgresql, subquery, sqldatatypes

I am trying to sum up the values from a column, resulting from a subquery.

My code is as follows:

```
select reg_code, year, sum(share) from (
select distinct on(id, seq) reg_code, year, id, share from t
) as t_
    group by reg_code, year
        order by reg_code, year
```

I was checking the results with an exemplary condition (region-year), namely where `reg_code = 'HU323' and year = 1996` applies.

The subquery yields the following result for this condition:

```
reg_code year   id          share
"HU323"  1996   24524639    0.50000000000000000000
"HU323"  1996   26318251    0.0769230769230769
"HU323"  1996   27417479    0.50000000000000000000
"HU323"  1996   46279087    0.50000000000000000000
```

Moreover, running

```
select reg_code, year, sum(share) from (
select distinct on(id, seq) reg_code, year, id, share from t
    where reg_code = 'HU323' and year = 1996
) as t_
    group by reg_code, year
        order by reg_code, year
```

yields

```
"HU323" 1996    1.57692307692307690000
```

, as expected.

However, if I run this query without the condition, the specific region-year combination is ignored and I cannot find it in the output (but there are other region-years in the output).

I am wondering if it has to do with messed up data types (share is numeric), but the summation works once I specify the WHERE condition

Comment: which version of postgres are you using, tried your example and it works fine without the condition: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e661e/10 postgres version in the fiddle is 9.6

Comment: Postgres version is 9.5. Your mini example works for me as well, but only if I create the table only for the given region-year combination.

Comment: can you create a fiddle just like the one I posted on the same site? that would help addressing the issue.

Comment: You have not provided input table definition (DDL) nor sample input data; you only provide the results of 1 sample, then inquire why another didn't work. Please supply input data - as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) - **no images**. But when ignoring specific region-year (guess that means removing where clause) that combination would only show up if by random choice is appeared first in a particular id, seq. There is nothing weird about it; it's just that distinct on does not include those columns.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. It was indeed a stupid "DISTINCT ON" mistake. I didn't consider that before reading your comment...